# Using the firewall extension in WiX

Tags: windows, wix, wix-extension

I'm trying to write a WiX script that uses the firewall extension to WiX, and it doesn't seem to find the extension dll (I think).

The error I'm seeing is this:

> The File element contains an unhandled extension element 'fire:FirewallException'.
>   Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com
>   /wix/FirewallExtension' namespace has been provided.

and the relevant part of my WiX source is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:fire="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension">
 <Component Id="Firewall" Guid="7278f07d-de6f-497f-9267-d5feb5216a5c" Directory="NotUsed">
  <File KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java.exe">
   <fire:FirewallException Id="FWX1" Name="My Program" Port="80" Protocol="tcp"/>
```

If i try to register the WixFirewallExtension.dll file with regsrv32 i get this error:

> The module C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML
>   v3.5\bin\WixFirewallExtension.dll was loaded but the entry-point
>   DllRegisterServer was not found.
>
> Make sure that C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML
>   v3.5\bin\WixFirewallExtension.dll is a valid DLL or OCX file and then
>   try again

The dll file is in my path, but that might not matter? Do i need to do anything else to get WiX to start using it?

Comment: Why did you try to register the WixFirewallExtension.dll?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer after some more digging:

I needed to specify the extension on the commandline of light.exe, like this:

```
light myfile.wxs -ext WixFirewallExtension -out myfile.wixobj
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with the visual studio plugin? I can't find the .dll anywhere

Comment: I found it in Program Files (x86)/Wix Toolset/bin

Answer (score 4):

You must add the reference of  "**WixFirewallExtension.dll**" inside your WIX Project to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "WixFirewallExtension.dll" inside your WIX Project will resolve the issue.
To do it follow the below steps:-

> - Open the project in visual studio.
> - Right click on wix project
> - Add reference to the above dll...